# Is a subclass of a "Serializable" class automatically "Serializable"?

Tags: java, serialization

Does a child class of a class that implements the `Serializable` interface also implement `Serializable`?  In other words, can instances of the child class also be serialized?

Comment: From javadoc "All subtypes of a serializable class are themselves serializable". Read javadoc please.

Comment: @talex - it is not as simple as that.  See my answer,

Comment: This is true of all interfaces, not just `Serializable`.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

> I wanted to ask whether the child of the parent, which implements "Serializable" interface, implements "Serializable" interface too, or in other words can that child be serialized?

The answer to the first part is Yes.  It is a natural consequence of Java inheritance.

The answer to the second part ("in other words ...") is Not Always<sup>1</sup>!

Consider this:

```
public class Parent implements Serializable {
    private int i;
    // ...
}

public class Child extends Parent {
    private Thread t = new Thread();   // a non-serializable object
    // ...
}
```

An instance of `Parent` can be serialized, but an instance of `Child` cannot ... because it has an attribute whose type (`Thread`) does not  implement `Serializable`.  If you attempt to serialize a `Child` instance with a non-null `t` field, you will get an exception.

Now if `t` was declared as `transient`, or if `Child` avoided using the default serialization mechanism, `Child` could be made to be serializable.  But my point is that serializability is an *emergent property*, not an inheritable property.

---

<sup>1 - This is notwithstanding what *you think* that the javadocs say!</sup>

Comment: Well yes but the same applies to `Parent`.

Comment: Correct.  The question is about what happens when you create a subclass ...

Answer (score 9):

Yes. If a parent implements `Serializable` then any child classes are also `Serializable`.

```
static class A implements Serializable {
}

static class B extends A {
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Serializable b = new B(); // <-- this is a legal statement. 
}
```

`B` also implements `Serializable`.

Answer (score 0):

If Parent class possess the Serializable behavior then by default all child class possess the Serializable behavior.

```
class Parent implements Serializable{

    int x;

}

class Children extends Parent{

    int m;
    public static void main(String args[]){
    Children c = new Children();
    c.m =10;
    c.x =20;
    // Enter Serialization Code;
    // Enter De serialization Code;
}
}
```

Note : When you read deserialize object, you will be able to retrieve serialize state.

Comment: Redundant answer.  It just repeats things said by earlier answers.